# Blender 2.8 wm.py Error line 524 and lin3 83 and more i didn't understan

Tags: python, error, osx

Please can someone help me white is error i tried everything i could but i can't fixed and even bought python runner, delete Blender "2.80" several time and download it didn't work! "macOS"
https://photos.app.goo.gl/kZVzgEtxKwd4JoFi9

Comment: Have you installed any add-ons before this error appeared? Can you try to do a factory reset (Edit > Preferences, click the button in the bottom left corner *Load Factory Preferences* and the save the preferences)

Comment: The error is displayed when I click the left mouse button in the blender window
it has nothing to do with addon " I mean all addon is working"

Comment: Did you try the factory reset?

Comment: you might want to check out this question:  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/148163/on-the-verge-of-quitting-blender