# Cant get add-ons to work

Tags: add-on

cant get any addons to work or anyone to answer what folder hidden or not to delete for clean install. I need these addons to work i wasted the last 8 hours i couldve been working trying to get blender cloud working. I need it for texturing. I quit. Last time this happened i had to take a year off due to the lack of resources to help me find and solve issues. I really love blender but im at my wits end with it . beta everything worked fine, now full release and i lost every add on i am paying for other then hard ops no issues with its operation whatsoever.
[image]

[image]

Comment: There does not seem to be any question here. This is a question and answer site. It is more for specific questions and answers about Blender, then for emotional rants. I think you should do what you want in life - if using Blender makes you unhappy, don't use it. 3d graphics is not for everybody - that's fine. Blender User preference files are in %appdata%\Blender Foundation\Blender\ (paste it in file explorer's address bar) on Windows.

Comment: Looks like there is an attempt to load a dll that doesn't work on x86. Can you check if starting the .zip version for 32-bit works? https://www.blender.org/download/Blender2.80/blender-2.80-windows32.zip/

Comment: There is a question.  he want's to know what the heck is happening.

Comment: hey let us know if @rjg's suggestion works or no.

Comment: Im, not a trained artist I am emotional and frustrated with thwapping my head against a wall. How or if that affected you personally my apologies. I just want to continue creating and am at a loss.

Comment: It did not work I constantly get a runtime error dialogue box that continues to pop up. I took a screenshot but see nowhere to add it to the thread ill try editing the original thread to include the image. when I tried to reactivate blender cloud add-on in preferences I got what appeared to be the same error that blender was doing before. I am really perplexed I think complete windows reformat and reinstall is my only option anyone I have spoken with is stumped. Seems to only be affecting add-ons that affect materials. hard ops and box cutter still working flawlessly.

Comment: SOLVED!
As I had mentioned maybe here earlier i just wanted to erase all traces of blender and start fresh install which I did and all is well. the directory i was trying to locate was C:/Users/[USER NAME]/AppData/Roaming/Blender Foundation/Blender).

Comment: Hurrah for you!  So glad you figured out the problem.  I hope that now you can finally enjoy Blender!

Comment: that's awesome!

Answer (score 1):

erase C:/Users/[USER NAME]/AppData/Roaming/Blender Foundation/Blender). and reinstall